# Incorrect username or password when using docker login without filling credentials in

Tags: docker, authorization, devops

Currently trying to log in to docker so I can push some images during my CI build, I'm getting this error when running `echo mypassword | docker login --username myusername --password-stdin`

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

However when I run `docker login` and fill in my credentials, it works and logs me in successfully.
This isn't a solution for me because I'm running this in my CI build (Travis), issue isn't related to travis because it doesn't work locally either.

I have tried the following commands:

`docker login --username myusername --password mypassword`

`docker login -u myusername -p mypassword`

`echo mypassword | docker login -u myusername --password-stdin`

Also reset my password to double-check the credentials were correct, but that didn't work, I am able to login when filling in my credentials, able to log in in Docker for Windows GUI and able to log in in the website. Simply doesn't work when specifying both credentials with paramaters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of variable, use a file to save the password. You can keep that file somewhere safe on Travis server. Try the below code

```
cat path/to/password/file/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin
```

For more more details, read [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) docker page

Comment: Turns out the issue was my password having special characters, changed it to a password with no special characters and worked fine. Disappointing tbh.

Comment: Use password with special character and try by encapsulating it in double quotes